# detect if website login failed objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

Just a quick one how do i detect if a login failed here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnTimetable:(id)sender {
    NSString *user = _txtUsername.text;
    NSString *pass = _txtPassword.text;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", user, pass];
    NSData *data =[content dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postlenght=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[data length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://moodle.thomroth.ac.uk/login/index.php?mode=login"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postlenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    //NSError *error=nil;
    //NSURLResponse *response=nil;
    //NSData *result=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    [self performSelector:@selector(parseTimetable) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

i dont even know where to start on this one is there a delegate method to detect such actions ?

Comment: UIWebView might have issues when storing credentials, and possibly not even support authentication (yet). If possible, you can download the data and set it afterward for the WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the official Developer forums, UIWebView does not support authentication challenges in iOS. Please read here (requires developer account): [UIWebView does not directly support authentication challenges](https://devforums.apple.com/message/904426#904426.)

`sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` should return `nil` and the status code of the returned response should equal `401` (Unauthorized):

```
[(NSHTTPURLRequest*)response statusCode] == 401
```

I would guess, the error parameter should be set to a corresponding error (please check this through printing it to the console).

If you use the delegate approach of `NSURLConnection` the situation is different:

When `NSURLConnection` receives a 401 (for example, the connection requires credentials for authentication, or a previous authentication attempt failed), it does invoke the delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

if implemented, otherwise it invokes these (now considered obsolete methods):

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;

- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

if implemented.

The official documentation provided more information: [NSURLConnectionDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

You can cancel the authentication request, if you decide to do so. As a result, the connection can fail.

If the connection fails, `connection:didFailWithError` will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it using UIWebView you could use it's delegate method and parse code answer of your website.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *webSource = [_web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
}
```